# Solved - Not a specific thread but everything in taskmgr uses 100% of HDD in total upon starting (Windows 10)

Tags: hard-drive

Solution: I simply deleted Intel RST software and everything including the random BSODs that I didn't mention here is solved after 2.5 years.

I've this situation for like 2.5 years and I can't bear it anymore.

As I've told above, upon starting the OS, HDD usage is 100%. I randomly terminate the programs that are using the highest portion of disk resources, right away some new random program takes place and uses high percentages of the disk resources again. And this continues no matter how hard I try, so there's no specific program that causes it - I suppose. The startup lasts 10 minutes. After 10 minutes, when I execute a random program, it also takes forever to load in the first attempt.

I've been debating for 2.5 years to reinstall the OS but I have arounds 800GB of data that I'd not want them to be deleted. I don't have this problem on Ubuntu or Slax. Everything works as expected.

Since Ubuntu works perfectly, I was wondering that if it's more likely that I have a faulty W10 instead of a faulty Hard Drive.

Please help!

Edit: Added S.M.A.R.T data below.

[image]

Edit: Added Event Viewer Info (Only Errors) Below:

[image]

Comment: This is typical for Windows.

Comment: Maybe it's just updates that you keep terminating? Or an antivirus or anti-malware scanning? Better boot it and let it sit there for a while. Of course, also make sure that you actually need all the things that are running on startup and remove the ones you don't need. Also check the Windows partitions for errors. Or maybe you have the Windows partition almost full becaue you have 3 OSes?

Comment: I didn't have other OSes before, but I had the same situation. 

For example when I terminate A.exe that uses 99% HDD at the instance when B.exe was %1, then suddenly B.exe starts to use 99% HDD.

I've already managed the startup and it didn't solve the problem as well. 

Are the partitions OS specific? That sounded interesting, I'd never tried that. Thanks for the suggestions!

@GabrielaGarcia

Comment: Yes, the partitions definitely are OS specific (except in specific situations with different Windows versions but any Linux is necessarily installed in its own). And what you described now about the AB processes is normal. Again, my advice is to let it sit for a while and I agree with @Scott (in this occasion ;))

Comment: But it takes almost 20 mins to load a program along with starting the OS is it still normal to you? 

I just want to know if it'd worth to fresh-install W10 back again. But I'll check the partitions as you've said. @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: Well, it depends. If Windows is trying to install a big update -or- there's any kind of scan running then it's sort of normal, unfortunately. One of the reasons I don't use Windows.

Comment: I am sure there are no scans running or no updates that is being installed. I guess I am going to check partitions and if it'd not help, I'll reinstall.

Comment: What processor, and what ram?

Comment: Many laptops these days come with painfully slow hard drives that are awful for causing this. The only things you can do are to either boot up the machine before you need it or get an SSD which will get rid of the problem completely.

Comment: Intel i7-4710HQ along with 16GB RAM @JohnnyVegas

Comment: @Mokubai I have a friend that has the completely same PC and he has no such problems.

Comment: What do you have installed that he doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is absolutely abnormal. Here are some suggestions:

- Check the Event Viewer for useful errors or warnings
- Run chkdsk
- Check S.M.A.R.T. data of the disk using a utility such as
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)
- Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to examine what these processes are doing
- If you think you might be infected, run a few deep scans by well-known anti-virus
  products. See also [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).

Comment: normal or abnormal? I've seen this on many machines, specifically if the machine is performing updates...

Comment: @Stese: Sure, but it's abnormal that it's not one particular app but all of them.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for exactly understanding the situation instead making assumptions before! I've checked the Event Viewer but there are so many information including errors, warnings and infos. Is there any specific type that I should care about? Or any source that I can check the errors & warnings because I couldn't find the reasons of some of them on Google. 

I don't think it's infected because I "usually" (I don't like to speak assured) am aware of what I am downloading, or what sites that I am surfing.

chkdsk didn't help before I've already tried it. But I have no idea about S.M.A.R.T

Comment: @harrymc I'll surely try to check that S.M.A.R.T data. Thanks for helpful answer!

Comment: Include in your post at least one screenshot of errors from the Event Viewer, just for me to get a feeling for it.

Comment: Another thing to try is to create a new admin login then see if the problem persists within that login.

Comment: Checking S.M.A.R.T data via CrystalDiskInfo showed me a warning about "Reallocated Sectors Count", threshold is 140, the value is 200.

Comment: It usually means you had 200 bad sectors on the disk that were mapped to spare sectors. This is not good. Maybe you could post a screenshot of all the values.

Comment: I've included it in the original question right now.

Comment: Nope, it seems like after all you had only one reallocated sector, which isn't too serious. The disk seems ok, so it looks more and more like an infection. Could you please add a screenshot of the list of errors in the Event Viewer?

Comment: Specifically arounds the startup time or all of them?

Comment: Just one screen of the errors list to start with.

Comment: Included them as well, sorry for my OS language I tried my best to make translations on thescreenshot.

Comment: I only included the first screen of errors in the "System" section adding just in case if it matters. The power errors are probably due to BSODs I started to get recently but I think it's completely an out of subject error.

Comment: It doesn't still encourage confidence in your computer. I think it's time for some deep anti-virus scanning before passing to more consequent operations. You are a careful person, as we all try to be, but better be sure before we deploy the big guns.

Comment: Is Malwarebytes or Kaspersky okay to do the scan? Thanks for all efforts by the way!

Comment: I suggest both of them.

Comment: Weirdly, I solved the problem after all 2.5 years by simply deleting Intel Rapid Storage Technologies software.

Comment: I don't really like this solution, although RST doesn't seem to be useful if you don't have an SSD. I would also still be keeping an eye on the Event Viewer.